# String representation of all values of nums, with the values separated by spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

Return a string with an array's contents, formatted with spaces.
For example, given the array {3,4,5,6} the string should look like this:
3 4 5 6
Spaces at the end of the string will not affect test results.
You will need to use a for loop here. Again, the structure of that loop would look similar to a previous problem.
However, this challenge introduces the idea that a for loop can manipulate a variable that exists outside of the
for loop, which looks something like this:

```
 String str;
 for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
 //do something to str here
 }
 return str;
```

Where i represents a variable that is used to visit every number between 0 and the length of nums. Inside of the
for loop, you will need to write code that appends elements from nums to str, one by one, in the format described above.

```
 @param nums the array to be manipulated.
 @return a string representation of all values of nums, with the values separated by spaces.       


    public class ReturnArrayContents {

    public String arrayToString(int[] nums){
  return null;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the final expected result regarding an input ?

Comment: You assign a literal to the result instead of using the array elements. Why? Bear in mind `java.util.Arrays.toString` already exists

Comment: Basically, I was being tasked with creating the for loop so that it would return a string representation of all values of nums, with the values separated by spaces. I was adding useless code that did not do what was being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually doing quite nothing to reach your goal, you don't use `nums` values, and have defined a strange `String string = "[1 , 2, 3, 4]";`

---

You need to append all the values of `nums` to reach your goal, here are some ways

An array-style with existing method

```
// '[1, 5, 8, 98]'
public static String arrayToString(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.toString(nums);
}
```

A concatenatde-values style

```
// '1,5,8,98'
public static String arrayToString(int[] nums) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";
    for (int num : nums) {
        result.append(separator).append(num);
        separator = ",";
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Same with brackets

```
// '[1,5,8,98]'
public static String arrayToString(int[] nums) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");
    String separator = "";
    for (int num : nums) {
        result.append(separator).append(num);
        separator = ",";
    }
    return result.append("]").toString();
}
```